# how to deny access to certain URLs which is not allowed by the admin to use?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.2`.

User is created by admin.
when user login to his page,can access the pages which is not allowed by the admin to use.
I want to restrict the user from accessing pages which is not issued by the admin to use.
    Admin assigns roles to each user.
when user login to his page,he can see the admin assigned pages.
But user can access pages with the help of URLs.
These URLs are not issued by the admin to use.controller part is given below.

```
//controller part
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\CreateEmployee;
use DB;
use App\Area;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Validator;
use App\make;

class CreateEmployeeController extends AdminController {
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index() { }

    public function addemployee() {
        $employee = CreateEmployee::where('id','<>',1)->get();
        $shop = Area::all();
        return view('app.admin.employee.createemployee',compact('employee','shop'));
    }

    public function saveemployee(Request $request) {
        $title = 'Add Employee';
        $employee = new CreateEmployee();
        $employee ->username = $request->username;
        $employee ->area_name = $request->area;
        $employee ->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $employee ->employee = 'yes';
        $employee ->admin = 1;
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
            ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('admin\create-employee')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
        }
        else {
            $employee->save();
            Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Employee Created Successfully'));
            return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee');
        }
    }

    public function editemployee($id) {
        $employee = CreateEmployee::where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('app.admin.employee.editemployee',compact('employee'));
    }

    public function updateemployee(Request $request) {
        CreateEmployee::where('id',$request->id)->update(array('username'=>$request->username,'area_name'=>$request->area));
        Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Employee Details Updated Successfully')); 
        return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee',array('id' => $request->id));
    }

    public function deleteconfirms($id) {
        $employee= CreateEmployee::find($id);
        $employee->delete();
        Session::flash('flash_notification', array('level' => 'success', 'message' => 'Employee Deleted Successfully'));
        return redirect()->action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@addemployee');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about middlewares, it should be able to satisfy your needs. Read link https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware